# Android OpenCV 2.4.6 Static Initialization Issue: Error in add-application.mk

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, static-linking

I was trying to build a simple project with OpenCV on Android. I was following the tutorial for static initialization (without JNI) so I don't need to use the OpenCV Manager apk. However the project keeps giving me the following error:

> make: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
>   line 176, external location: C:\AndroidTools\android-ndk-r9\build\core\add-application.mk

I can clean the project, delete the error and just export the project to apk successfully, but this error will just keep coming out. I am curious if anybody has encountered this and found a solution? It is just annoying I have to delete the error over and over again if I made some changes to the program.